# How to cluster/classify search query

Tags: machine-learning, search, classification, cluster-analysis, keyword

**Background:** 
I have a dataset from a small search portal site. The dataset includes all the search queries / keywords users searched for.

The format is like

```
Keyword    num_of_searches
Yahoo      5098
Google     8873
エロ動画    98982
...        ...
```

(The portal site is in JP, so there are lots of Japanese keywords in the dataset.)

**Question:**

Is there any existing machine learning models that allow me to classify all the keywords into a few categories?
(I have heard of "keyword clustering", but I don't now which model to use.)

Comment: On what basis would this operate? Garbage in garbage out - the result will only be as informative as the input you have. So you could "cluster" terms by frequency which is rather pointless, but not by meaning, because where *is* the meaning in machine-preadable form?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using pretrained word embeddings then doing clustering on the embedding vectors. Word embeddings could be visualized https://projector.tensorflow.org using t-SNE or PCA to gain more insights.